# Post revision shows a different user edited the answer

Tags: discussion, revision-history

I've just stumbled across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4460/2246344) answer, which shows Jeff as the last editor,

> [image]

But, when I view the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4460/revisions) it displays deceze as the editor.

> [image]

So, who's the real editor here? (Is this a bug?)

Comment: Note that Jeff Atwood's edition is on Aug 9, while deceze's is on Aug 7. So somehow Jeff's is not appearing in the revision log.

Answer (score 37):

It's unlikely to be a bug... it's probably Jeff hacking the DB in the early days of SO. I'd guess that he deleted a revision from the `PostHistory` table but didn't backfill the change to the denormalised version in the `Posts` table that's (probably) used to render the question page.

Data.SE (probably) confirms this hypothesis. The [`LastEditorUserId` in the `Posts` table](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/223092) is Jeff; but [the only edit in the `PostHistory` table is deceze's](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/223093).

I'd only call this a bug in that there's nothing to confirm consistency between the data that states the official truth and the data that's been denormalised for display. Whether you want this is a balance between determining the likelihood of data being incorrect vs. the loss of service if it is vs. the amount of system resources necessary to ensure the denormalised data is correct. My checks run daily :-).